# Initializing a variable with the input of a process

Tags: vhdl

I have been trying to think of ways to reduce the scope of indexing variables used in a mux. Today I came up with using something like the code below as a strategy:

```
entity control is
  port (
    sel_slv       : in   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    in0, in1, in2 : in   std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    out           : out  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0))
end Control;
architecture rtl of Control is 
begin
  mux : process(sel_slv, in0, in1, in2, in3)
    variable sel : integer := to_integer(unsigned(sel_slv));
  begin
    case sel is
      when 0 =>      outp <= in0;
      when 1 =>      outp <= in1;
      when 2 =>      outp <= in2;
      when others => outp <= (others => '-');
    end case;
  end process mux;
end rtl;
```

I noticed that modelsim gives a warning: Initial value of "sel" depends on value of signal "sel_slv". 
I assumed that sel would be initialized every time the process was run.

Comment: It'll work as expected in VHDL, perhaps not what you might expect. A variable declaration is not a sequential assignment statement. Without any further assignments to sel it's initial value will be the  that will be the converted initial value of sel_sv. Add a variable assignment statement for sel before the case statement with the expression currently used as the initial value as the right hand side expression. The initial value would be redundant. Consider simulating your design specification. Tell us how you expect your code example to work.

Comment: I assumed the variable initialization happened every time the process was run.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.6 Dynamic elaboration para 2 b): *Execution of a subprogram call involves the elaboration of the parameter association list.* That doesn't include the variable declaration, see 14.4.2 Elaboration of a declaration, 14.4.2.2 Subprogram declarations, bodies and instantiations and 14.4.2.5 Object declarations. A declaration here can be thought of as reserving space and providing an address for a stack variable. Note the function to_integer declares it's formal parameters, the function call elaborates the association list.

Comment: The key to understanding what it did do, is that the function to_integer was only called during elaboration of the interface list, and only during initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes are not procedures. A process variable holds its value between activations of that process - that's how it HAS to work, otherwise you couldn't use variables in a process to represent memories or registers or state in a state machine.

Read your code with that understanding : the variable is initialised once, and never assigned to again.

Your own answer is fine as to what to do about it; I just wanted to make the underlying reason a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

With the code as is `sel` will take the initial value of `sel_slv` and never change. Moving the variable initialization statement after the begin makes the process respond to changes in `sel_slv` as expected.

```
entity control is
  port (
    sel_slv       : in   std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    in0, in1, in2 : in   std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    out           : out  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0))
end Control;
architecture rtl of Control is 
begin
  mux : process(sel_slv, in0, in1, in2, in3)
    variable sel : integer;
  begin
    sel := to_integer(unsigned(sel_slv));
    case sel is
      when 0 =>      outp <= in0;
      when 1 =>      outp <= in1;
      when 2 =>      outp <= in2;
      when others => outp <= (others => '-');
    end case;
  end process mux;
end rtl;
```

Reminder for next time: Variables initialized in a process are initialized during elaboration (compile) time.

From the VHDL spec:

IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.6 Dynamic elaboration para 2 b): Execution of a subprogram call involves the elaboration of the parameter association list. That doesn't include the variable declaration, see 14.4.2 Elaboration of a declaration, 14.4.2.2 Subprogram declarations, bodies and instantiations and 14.4.2.5 Object declarations. A declaration here can be thought of as reserving space and providing an address for a stack variable.